Get purchases coming from an Google Ads with Google Analytics API
After payment on our website we trigger a 'conversion' tag to our Gads property with gtag(). Our google Tag manager has also a conversion Linker set and also a tag property that "catch" this post payment page.
Our Google Analytics account is linked to our Google Ads account.
What I want to know is which payments come from a user that reach or site from a Google Ads using Google Analytics Dashboards and using Google Analytics API.
I Tried different ways (metrics/dimensions) but can't find a way where the value returned might be correct.
To summarize : I  want to know how to get payments that's originally come from a click on a google Ads, this using Google Analytics API.
Thanks for a help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks. Finally I  want to know how to get payments that's originally come from a click on a google Ads using Google Analytics API. I had this in my question.
